# How can I use ros-fawkes plugins and fawkes_msgs node with ROS-Melodic?

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to use `navgraph` plugin of the `fawkes`. I try to follow [installation guide](https://trac.fawkesrobotics.org/wiki/ROSIntegration) of `fawkes`. But I got make error 1 and 2 which is not the topic for ros answers.

Since I couldn't install `fawkes`, I wonder if I can use `navgraph` package on its own. Is it possible to add `navgraph` as a plugin?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/342982/how-can-i-use-ros-fawkes-plugins-and-fawkes_msgs-node-with-ros-melodic?/) by [wallybeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/46586/wallybeam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 57 on 2020-01-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want to use `Fawkes` and `ROS` together, download the latest version of `Fawkes` from their [github directory](https://github.com/fawkesrobotics/fawkes/releases/tag/1.3.0). Then follow the steps given in their website.

```
git clone git://git.fawkesrobotics.org/fawkes.git
cd fawkes
make all gui
```

Then to start `navgraph` you should start `fawkes` just like `roscore`. After that follow instructions related with the navgraph in their website.

For my application I find out that ros packages like [topological_navigation](http://wiki.ros.org/topological_navigation) are more helpful than navgraph.

---

Originally posted by [wallybeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/46586/wallybeam/) with karma: 57 on 2020-02-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0